# How to making different types of users in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am very new at android and firebase and this is my first question in stack.
I am making an app that is required to make different types of users (teacher - student) and every type has his own functionality.
I am using firebase to make the authentication and I am using email and password but I can't find how to but the user type.

What is the best way to do this with firebase?

Answer (score 1):

[Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) does not allow you to set the type of a user (teacher or student). You can choose in your project to have regulars users or [admins](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/).

As a quick solution, just add a two new nodes in you firebase database named `teachers` and `students` in which you can add each teacher/student with his own details.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Seif An alternate strategy would be to add a child node to each users node: /users/user_type: teacher or /users/user_type: student.

Comment: That's right Jay, this is another approach. Thanks!